# How do I use the same PatternLayout with multiple Appenders in Log4j2?

Tags: log4j2

I have a set of appenders like this...

```
<Console name="console">
    <PatternLayout pattern="..." />
</Console>
<RollingFile name="file" ...>
    <PatternLayout pattern="..." />
</RollingFile>
...
```

Now there are a bunch of these, and the patterns are all the same. I have looked through the Log4J2 docs and can't find anything (although I am sure I am just missing it).

Can I create a single pattern layout and use it for all of the appenders?

Answer (score 2):

There is one indirect way to doing this using properties -

1. Define the property in the beginning of the configuration file under `Configuration` element -

   ```
    <Properties>
        <Property name="layout">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %msg%n</Property>
    </Properties>
   ```
2. Refer to this property in each appender -

   ```
   <Console name="console">
       <PatternLayout pattern="${layout}" />
   </Console>
   <RollingFile name="file" ...>
       <PatternLayout pattern="${layout}" />
   </RollingFile>
   ```